# Terraform command not recognized in Gitlab Windows Runners

Tags: gitlab, terraform, devops, gitlab-ci-runner, terraform-provider-aws

I setup Gitlab runner on a local Windows machine. There are some jobs defined, but one of them is "terraform version", but the job failed in Gitlab CI, below is the error,

```
$ terraform version
terraform: The term 'terraform' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Note: Terraform works fine locally without Gitlab when executed from the working directory.

Can someone through some lights here, thanks.

Comment: you need to install terraform in gitlab runner

Comment: I have tried adding the command in yml file to download curl -0 https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.13.5/terraform_0.13.5_windows_amd64.zip --output terraform_0.13.5_windows_amd64.zip -d C:\GitLab-Runner\ and also tried placing the terraform executable file in the path where the all the files on the gitlab are created in the local windows machine, but still no luck....

Comment: Try running `which terraform` command & paste the output. Downloading terraform alone isn't necessary it has to be in some path and executable.

Comment: Unfortunately whch terraform don't work in Windows Powershell where gitlab runner is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As windows issue is not resolved or can't be resolved in my case, i have tried another option ie. by installing Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)  on the same windows machine.
Thanks all.